# jquery.form get plain HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I am trying to get plain HTML as response in the plugin jquery.form.js (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), but I can't get it. So my code looks like that:

```
print "$('#filter_form').ajaxForm({
            target:'#ajax1',
    beforeSend: function() {
      console.log('Image uploading started.');
      img_status.fadeOut();
      img_slider.width('0%');
      img_percent_text.html('0%');
    },
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
  console.log('Image upload update...');
  img_slider.width(percentComplete + '%');
  img_percent_text.html(percentComplete + '%')
},

complete: function(responseText, statusText, xhr) {
    img_slider.width('100%');
    img_percent_text.html('100%')
    console.log('Image uploading finished!');
    img_preview.fadeOut(800);
    alert(responseText);
}

  });";

print "});";
print '</script>';
```

And for some reason this is changing the target wrong, take a look at the code...

```
if (empty($_POST)) {
...... // I get this code as output
}
else{
print "this should be the output via ajax";
}
```

So the questions are:

How to get the plain HTML in the complete function (responseText returns object)

How to fix the post parameters that i'm sending through ajax ?

Comment: How do you test forms in jsfiddle, I don't see PHP option in there

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the `empty` function returns `FALSE` if you pass in an empty array().

So if you make a POST with no fields (params) then `empty($_POST)` returns `FALSE`.

If you want to check if the request is of type POST then either check if the $_POST variable is set using the `isset($_POST)` method or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'`.

Comment: I use it because the form action leads to the same page where the form is, so if there is no post query I print the form and if there is I just process the submitted post parameters. I will try the isset()...

Comment: Ok, just wanted to point out that your if statement won't work when you make a post with no parameters. But if you expect to always have parameters then it should't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the REQUEST_METHOD :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also append your response text/html object to some HTML entities, example

```
$('#my_id').html(responseText);

<div id='my_id'></div>
```

Comment: responseText returns [object Object] and I've already tried that and the code in the div was left unchanged.

Comment: just turned out that in this object there is another responseText and when I type responseText.responseText it does show the output correctly, but the post query is wrong again

Answer (score 0):

So here were my mistakes:

1.How to get the response as plain HTML?

responseText is object, which contains responseText.

```
Just use responseText.responseText\
```

How I found it out:
I used

```
console.log(responseText)
```

to output the object in the browser console and I found out that the source code is in responseText.

2.The problem with the post method

I red that this plugin gets the method from the form so there are two fixes - force it with param

```
type: 'POST'
```

in

```
$('...').ajaxForm({
```

or simply set the form method to post like that:

```
<form action="example.com" method="post" ></form>
```